# How to alter keys in immutable map?

Tags: immutable.js, normalizr

I've a data structure like this (generated by normalizr):

```
const data = fromJS({
  templates: {
    "83E51B08-5F55-4FA2-A2A0-99744AE7AAD3":
      {"uuid": "83E51B08-5F55-4FA2-A2A0-99744AE7AAD3", test: "bla"},
    "F16FB07B-EF7C-440C-9C21-F331FCA93439":
      {"uuid": "F16FB07B-EF7C-440C-9C21-F331FCA93439", test: "bla"}
  }
})
```

Now I try to figure out how to replace the UUIDs in both the key and the value of the template entries. Basically how can I archive the following output:

```
const data = fromJS({
  templates: {
    "DBB0B4B0-565A-4066-88D3-3284803E0FD2":
      {"uuid": "DBB0B4B0-565A-4066-88D3-3284803E0FD2", test: "bla"},
    "D44FA349-048E-4006-A545-DBF49B1FA5AF":
      {"uuid": "D44FA349-048E-4006-A545-DBF49B1FA5AF", test: "bla"}
  }
})
```

A good candidate seems to me the `.mapEntries()` method, but I'm struggling on how to use it ...

```
// this don't work ... :-(
const result = data.mapEntries((k, v) => {
  const newUUID = uuid.v4()
  return (newUUID, v.set('uuid', newUUID))
})
```

Maybe someone can give me a hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapEntries` is the correct method. From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mapEntries), the mapping function has the following signature:

```
mapper: (entry: [K, V], index: number, iter: this) => [KM, VM]
```

This means that the first argument is the entry passed in as an array of [key, value]. Similarly, the return value of the mapper function should be an array of the new key and the new value. So your mapper function needs to look like this:

```
([k, v]) => {
  const newUUID = uuid.v4()
  return [newUUID, v.set('uuid', newUUID)]
}
```

This is equivalent to the following (more explicit) function:

```
(entry) => {
  const key = entry[0]; // note that key isn't actually used, so this isn't necessary
  const value = entry[1];
  const newUUID = uuid.v4()
  return [newUUID, value.set('uuid', newUUID)]
}
```

One thing to note is that the templates are nested under the `templates` property, so you can't map data directly -- instead you'll want to use the [update](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update) function.

```
data.update('templates', templates => template.mapEntries(...)))
```

So putting everything together, your solution should look like the following:

```
const result = data.update('templates', templates => 
  templates.mapEntries(([k, v]) => {
    const newUUID = uuid.v4()
    return [newUUID, v.set('uuid', newUUID)]
  })
);
```